# Preserve beanstalkd queue on restart or crash

Tags: queue, beanstalkd

I'm using `beanstalkd` to managed queues. I just realised that if there are jobs in a queue and the `beanstalkd` process is restarted or crashes then the job is lost forever (or so I think).

Is there a way to preserve the jobs in the queue on `beanstalkd` failure or restart? If not, whats best practice to ensure jobs are never lost?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beanstalkd can be started with the `-b` ([binary log](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/faq#are-the-jobs-persistent-what-happens-if-the-power-goes-out)) option, and beanstalkd will write all jobs to a binlog. If the power goes out, you can restart beanstalkd with the same option and it will recover the contents of the log.

Comment: How does one add the `-b` option when `beanstalkd` is started as a service?

Comment: Just add it to your `/etc/default/beanstalkd` 
like so: `DAEMON_OPTS="(your current options) -b /var/lib/beanstalkd"`